# Joint PMF $X~\operatorname{Ber}(0.5)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> [image]

**I am not sure:**

We have $p=0.5$ , so $q =0.5$ for both.

So joint pmf is given by :
$$P_{XY}(X=0.5,Y=0.5)$$
 ?? is this the answer or the question want something else ? What is the use covariance here?

Comment: This has nothing to do with [distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/distribution-theory/info). Removing tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some more help; the problem is a bit fiddly in Part (b).

### Part (a):

Let $X,Y\sim Ber(\frac{1}{2})$. Let $p_{ij}=P(X=i,Y=j)$ as suggested. Hence,
\begin{eqnarray*}
E[X]&=&E[Y]=(1)\frac{1}{2} + (0)\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\\
Var[X] &=& Var[Y] = E[(X-E[X])^2] = E[(Y-E[Y])^2] = \Big(1-\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2\frac{1}{2} + \Big(0-\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, $Cov[X,Y]=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$. We have $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ so compute $E[XY]$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
E[XY]&=&(1)(1)p_{11} + (1)(0)p_{10} + (0)(1)p_{01}+(0)(0)p_{00} = p_{11}
\end{eqnarray*}
So, we have
$$
Cov[X,Y]=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y] = p_{11}-\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big) = p_{11}-\frac{1}{4}
$$
and
$$
Corr[X,Y]=\frac{Cov[X,Y]}{\sqrt{Var[X]}\sqrt{Var[Y]}} 
= \frac{p_{11}-\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}} = 4p_{11}-1
$$
Set $Corr[X,Y]=4p_{11}-1=-\frac{2}{3}$ and you get $p_{11}=\frac{1}{12}$. Thus, by choosing $p_{11}=\frac{1}{12}$ we ensure the correlation is $-\frac{2}{3}$. Note that this does not put any restrictions on $p_{10}, p_{01}, p_{00}$.

With the choice of $p_{11}=\frac{1}{12}$ we now need to find the remaining $p_{00}, p_{01}, p_{10}$ such that the marginals are both $Ber(\frac{1}{5})$, as assumed, and that $p_{11}+p_{10}+p_{01}+p_{00}=1$.

First, note that $\frac{1}{2}=P(X=1) = P(X=1,Y=0)+P(X=1,Y=1) = p_{10}+p_{11}$ which implies $p_{10}=\frac{1}{2}-p_{11}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{12}=\frac{5}{12}$.

Next, note that $\frac{1}{2}=P(Y=1) = P(X=1,Y=1)+P(X=0,Y=1) = p_{11}+p_{01}$ which implies $p_{01}=\frac{1}{2}-p_{11}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{12}=\frac{5}{12}$.

Now, $\frac{1}{2}=P(X=0)=P(X=0,Y=0)+P(X=0,Y=1)=p_{00}+p_{01}$.  which implies $p_{00}=\frac{1}{2}-p_{01}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{5}{12}=\frac{1}{12}$.

And, $\frac{1}{2}=P(Y=0)=P(X=0,Y=0)+P(X=1,Y=0)=p_{00}+p_{10}$.  which implies $p_{00}=\frac{1}{2}-p_{01}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{5}{12}=\frac{1}{12}$ which we already have.

And we confirm that $p_{10}+p_{01}+p_{00}+p_{11}=1$.

### Part (b)

Let $X\sim Ber(\frac{1}{2})$ and $Z\sim Ber(p)$. As above, we get $E[X]=\frac{1}{2}$ and $Var[X]=\frac{1}{4}$. Let $q_{ij}=P(X=i,Z=j)$ be given.

\begin{eqnarray*}
E[Z] &=& 1\cdot p + 0\cdot (1-p) = p\\
Var[Z] &=& E[(Z-E[Z])^2] = (1-p)^2\cdot p + (0-p)^2 \cdot (1-p) = p(1-p)
\end{eqnarray*}

Following the calculation steps as above we get $E[XZ]=q_{11}$ and so
$Cov[X,Z]=E[XZ]-E[X]E[Z]=q_{11}-\frac{1}{2}p$. Hence,

$$
Corr[X,Z]=\frac{Cov[X,Z]}{\sqrt{Var[X]}\sqrt{Var[Z]}}
=\frac{q_{11}-\frac{1}{2}p}{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{p(1-p)}}
=\frac{2q_{11}-p}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}=-\frac{2}{3}
$$

So, the unknowns here are $q_{11}$ and $p$. The problem appears to want you to assume $q_{11}$ is known and you are finding the possible values of $p$ yielding $-\frac{2}{3}$ for the correlation in terms of the $q_{11}$. So, rearrange:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{2q_{11}-p}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}&=&-\frac{2}{3}\\
2q_{11}-p &=& -\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{p(1-p)}\\
(2q_{11}-p)^2 &=& \frac{4}{9} p(1-p)\\
4q_{11}^2-4q_{11}p+p^2 &=& \frac{4}{9} p(1-p)\\
36q_{11}^2-36q_{11}p+9p^2 &=& 4 p(1-p)\\
36q_{11}^2-36q_{11}p+9p^2 &=& 4 p -4p^2\\
13p^2-(4+36q_{11})p  +36q_{11}^2 &=& 0\\
p&=&\frac{4+36q_{11} \pm \sqrt{(4+36q_{11})^2-4(13)36q_{11}^2}}{2(13)}\\
p&=&\frac{4+36q_{11} \pm \sqrt{16+288q_{11}-576q_{11}^2}}{2(13)}
\end{eqnarray*}
which isn't very pretty. $q_{11}$ can't be any value in $[0,1]$ since the radicand has to be non-negative for a real solution. If the radicand is zero we get a single value of $p$ which we reject if outside of $[0,1]$ otherwise it answers the question. If The randicand is strictly positive we get two roots for $p$ and we reject any that are outside of $[0,1]$; for those that we don't reject we get possible probabilities $p$ that answer the question.

If we take $q_{11}=\frac{1}{12}$ from Part (a) then we end up with two real roots: 
$p=\frac{1}{2}$ and $p=\frac{1}{26}$, both of which are in $[0,1]$. The first value is to be expected, based on Part (a). The second one is new.

Comment: In a) the $p_{ij}$ are uniquely determined. You haven't accounted for the marginal Bernoulli distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Right! I'll fix that now...

Answer (score 0):

Note that $X,Y$ take on the values $\{0,1\}$ so the expression you have written will have probability $0$. Let $p_{ij} = P(X = i,Y = j), i,j \in \{0,1\}$. The information provided about the given marginal distributions says that $p_{00} + p_{01} = 0.5$ and similarly $p_{00} + p_{10} = 0.5$. You can calculate the covariance as $E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) = p_{11} - (1/2)^2$. You should be able to find what the variance of $X,Y$ are. From this you can solve for $p_{11}$. Using $p_{11} + p_{10} + p_{01} + p_{00} = 1$ you can find all of the $p_{ij}$'s which is exactly the joint pmf.

Comment: okay thanks ... let me try it, i will let you know after editing it

Comment: i tried and i dont understand :( this joint distributions are so new to me and i am not even sure Corr is covariance or correlation @amck

Comment: Corr is the correlation, $Cov(X,Y)$ is the covariance. It might be helpful to go back to the definition of what a joint pmf is. $P(X = a, Y = b)$ is simply a number for each choice of $a$ and $b$. So a joint pmf is a function $F(a,b) = P(X = a, Y = b)$. The question is asking you to find out what this function is, ie what number does it spit out for each choice of $a,b$?

Comment: thanks for trying it, i think i cant solve it. i appreciate your help